# Average marginal effects by hand?

Tags: logistic, marginal-effect, latent-class

I'm having trouble calculating average marginal effects by hand. I have the coefficients from Latent Gold (so if anyone knows how to get AMEs from that program, that would be helpful!).

Otherwise, I have a spreadsheet with the coefficients from the logit output, but I'm not sure how to calculate the average marginal effect by hand.

I've seen several sites (i.e. [Calculate Marginal effect by hand (without using packages or Stata or R) with logit and dummy variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448782/calculate-marginal-effect-by-hand-without-using-packages-or-stata-or-r-with-lo)) that indicate that the formula is:
$$p(y=1)*p(y=0)*\beta$$.

Say I'm interested in the average marginal effect of years of education on the outcome. Is $p(y=1)$ calculated by plugging in the mean of all the variables, including education, into the logit equation? And then multiplying by $\beta$ education? Or do I calculate $p(y=1)$ without holding education at it's mean, since it's the coefficient of interest?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

The *marginal effect of $X$ for a unit $i$* is the change in the probability of the event if you were to change $X$ by a very small amount from its value for unit $i$ while keeping all other covariates that the same value for unit $i$. That is, it's the change in probability if you were to change $X$ by a very small amount but not change anything else (measured) about that unit.

The *average marginal effect of $X$* is the average of the marginal effects of $X$ across all units in the sample. It's not the *marginal effect at the mean*, which is what you would get if you were to plug in the means of all the covariates into the logit function to calculate $p(y=1|X=\bar x)$, as you suggested.

You need to calculate $p(y_i=1|X=x_i)$ and $p(y_i=0|X=x_i) = 1- p(y_i=1|X=x_i)$ for every unit $i$ in your sample, then compute the average of $p(y_i=1|X=x_i)\times p(y_i=0|X=x_i)$ across all units, and multiply that average by $\beta$. This is the average marginal effect of the (continuous) predictor with coefficient $\beta$ (note the procedure is different for binary predictors). In a formula, this would be:
$$
\beta \frac{1}{N} \sum^N_{i=1} p(y_i=1|X=x_i) \times p(y_i=0|X=x_i)
$$

To do this manually, one unit at a time, compute their $p(y_i=1|X=x_i)$ and $p(y_i=0|X=x_i)$ by plugging in their values of $X$ (i.e., the covariates, including the focal covariate, e.g., education) into the logistic equation with the estimated coefficients. Do this for all units. Then take the average of $p(y_i=1|X=x_i) \times p(y_i=0|X=x_i)$ and multiply that average by the coefficient $\beta$ for the focal covariate. You can get the average marginal effect for other continuous covariates simply by substituting the corresponding $\beta$.